# Can I install anaconda on my account and make it available for others?

Tags: python

OS: Centos 7.2.1511
I have to install it on my account, for the administrator insists so. My classmates don't know python: they just want to use some scripts written by me, which rely on anaconda and they surely won't install one on their accounts. The only solution seems to be to install anaconda on my account and make it available for others. Is it possible?

Comment: Can you not do a common installation...

Comment: The administrator says 'No', if I didn't misunderstand your comment.

Comment: Well, then you should create a separate account and let everyone access it. If someone could access personal information in your account, that'd be a serious security issue.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks.